# How to send an email in C#  using a different email account than the logged in user

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop

I have a working form which sends emails from the default logged in account. I am trying to add a feature where the user can select an email account from a drop down list and send the emails via an alt address, like info@companyname.com or support@companyname.com. I am trying to use the "SendUsingAccount" option but no luck. I have look online but mostly find examples using VB which im not familiar with. My code is as follows:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var mic = (MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));
Inspector oAddSig = null;

mic.sendusingaccount = ??????????????     //here is where i need the help
mic.Subject = "Announcing Participant Website Enhancements!";
mic.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mic.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
//mic.Attachments.Add(PDFAttachment + yearending.Text + ".pdf");
object emailBody = ToolBox.GetStringFromTextFile((string)EmailBody);
oAddSig = mic.GetInspector;
mic.HTMLBody = emailBody + mic.HTMLBody;
//mic.Display(true);
mic.Send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I always use the SMTP client from the System.Net.Mail namespace.  It has a method called 'send' that allows you to provide the address of whom the message is 'from'

Check it out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

As long as you know the address of your exchange server (which should be OK since you are trying to use outlook in your example) everything should be A-OK.  Probably a bit easier than the approach above too.

Comment: I dont want to use smtp, I use this form in multiple apps. i just want to change the from address. how come the easiest stuff is the hardest???

Comment: You are making it hard by not using a proven solution.  Is there a reason why you can't use SMTP client?

Comment: for one im not sure of our smtp settings or even if it is configured. I couldnt even tell you the smtp server address.

Comment: Use the same address for the (exchange?) server that you are connecting your outlook clients to in the first place.  (As stated in the answer)

Comment: ive tried and tried to no end and it still dont work. any code samples?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a different question with code + information about how it "don't work"

Answer (score 2):

if you have a dropdown you could create a string with the value of that dd and asign sendusingaccount  = your string

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); 
    string email = yourdropdown.selectedvalue;
    var mic = (MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)); 
    Inspector oAddSig = null; 
    mic.sendusingaccount = email
```

I hope this help you

Comment: this is my preferred method but I get errors.. im working on it now. its not finding sendusingaccount, or it wants to convert "string email" into "account email" then it wont convert from string to account type.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Outlook.Account account =
    Application.Session.Accounts["Hotmail"];
mic.SendUsingAccount = account;
```

May be You can check the different accounts at Sessions...

You can check:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184652.aspx)